# StreamReader Windows Phone cannot read accented characters

Tags: windows-phone-7, streamreader, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to receive a response with a json using accented characters.

When I receive the response I do this:

```
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
```

When I output the results in a texblock or in a messagebox i get always the special characters replacement �.

Any Idea?

Comment: Are you sure the stream is encoded with UTF8? Have you tryed `Encoding.Default`?

Comment: Encoding.Default is not available for Windows Phone, so I solved the problem with "using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))"

Thanks!